# PHP img src (simple)

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add an image file to my PHP so when I echo, the picture will appear alongside the message. However I am getting a syntax error on line 3. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
 echo "President has been killed";
<IMG SRC = "D:/User Data\Documents/Sheridan/Summer Year 3/Enterprise Java Development/Projects/PhpAssignment/skull.png;"/>
?>
```

Comment: The closing tag `?>` has to be before `<img`

Comment: HTML tags are usually written in lower case, ditto attributes, so use `<img src="...">`. Note also that there are no spaces around the `=`. You can probably get away with upper case and/or spaces, since browsers tend to be very forgiving, but it is better to stick to the standards.

Comment: Also, your image as it stands will only work if it is the named folder - if your HTML file is in the same folder as `skull.png` then just use `<img src="skull.png">` rather than using the whole path name.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 echo 'President has been killed
       <img src="D:/User Data\Documents/Sheridan/Summer Year 3/Enterprise Java Development/Projects/PhpAssignment/skull.png;" /> ';

?>
```

Note the change in quotes -- single and double -- and placement of the semi-colon.

or

```
<?php
 echo "President has been killed";
?>
<img src="D:/User Data\Documents/Sheridan/Summer Year 3/Enterprise Java Development/Projects/PhpAssignment/skull.png;" />
```

Move the image *outside* the php. Using this depends on overall markup though.

The semi-colon ends, or stops the `echo` statement.

Comment: The semi-colon in the image path is probably wrong too.

Comment: @halfer that image path is all kinds of wrong for web applications, since it's a local directory path. But I wasn't going to guess at a proper path.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there's an syntax error. You are trying to output HTML inside PHP block:

Change your code to:

```
    <?php

    echo "President has been killed";

    ?>

    <IMG SRC = "D:/User Data\Documents/Sheridan/Summer Year 3/Enterprise Java Development/Projects/PhpAssignment/skull.png;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 echo "President has been killed";
<IMG SRC = "D:/User Data\Documents/Sheridan/Summer Year 3/Enterprise Java Development/Projects/PhpAssignment/skull.png;"/>
?>
```

firstly you don't need the entire location, place the image in the folder in your root called images then place the image in there.

```
    <?php 
    echo '<p>President has been killed<p><img src = "D:/User Data\Documents/Sheridan/Summer Year 3/Enterprise Java Development/Projects/PhpAssignment/skull.png"/>';
?>
```